# What tools exist that offer apk protection for android (against reversing and repackaging)?

Tags: android, security, apk, packer

Seems that one of my company's successful apps has been repackaged as a torjan and distributed on 3rd parties markets (outside of google play). I'm looking for a robust solution that will protect our apps from such issues in the future.

So far I've seen:

- http://www.droidactivator.org/
- http://www.androidlicenser.com/

But neither seem to deliver a comprehensive solution.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: By definition, what you want is impossible, on any OS. Anyone can take any app, reverse-engineer it, add in malware, and distribute the result. Obfuscation (e.g., ProGuard for Android apps) can slow things down, as can various other tricks (e.g., http://www.develop-online.net/blog/349/How-Android-developers-can-fight-piracy-bots-and-malware). But all they will do is slow things down, making it less likely somebody will fully scratch their itch to hack your app. Nothing can stop it outright.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Of course that there is no solution that protects 100% of the cases. Problem is that today it's extremely easy to take an application, change some of the code and repackage it as a real app. On the PC you can find many off-the-shelf products that make the process much harder. I'm looking for a solution that will works well against 80% of the "crackers" attempting to modify my app. Something similar to [armadillo](http://www.woodmann.com/crackz/Packers.htm#armadillo) for android

Comment: Any "comprehensive solution" is a magnet for those who can (and will) comprehensively break it. There were several cracks for various versions of Armadillo *on the very page that you linked to*. A search of the Internet shows various SoftwarePassport (the new name for Armadillo, apparently) cracks, and even free downloads of SoftwarePassport itself -- not exactly a testament to its defensive ability. This is one area that if you want it done right (or as right as it can get), you have to do it yourself, so that there is no existing off-the-shelf crack for your solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I disagree. I don't know how well you know this space (packers, protectors and reversing), but breaking the latest versions of armadillo was extremely difficult. Usually you could find cracks for earlier versions, but finding one for the newest was not easy. On most cases, people were able to create a crack for an app manually, but removing the armadillo automatically was much harder. On the mobile space, were an app cost 0.99$ crackers might not find it that cost-effective.

Comment: Building your own solution is costly if you want to create something that is hard to crack. If you are not willing to heavily invest, and/or if you don't have the team, you would probably create a very weak protector.

Comment: Our business developed about 90 apps, all of those use quixxi. http://quixxi.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at it from wrong perspective. Not sure about your exact case but normally the repackaged apps aren't "Reverse Engineered". i.e. the malware guy has little concern about the internals of your app. Trojan can be appended simply at the entry point of your application in which case the trojan would execute and then proceed to run your application. In such case obfuscation will not do anything except slow your application down.

Comment: I'm not looking for a good obfuscation. I'm looking for a protector - a software that modifies the original apps and adds a protection layer that prevents (up to a certain extent) modifications and repackaging.